# Why does BigInteger end up with StackOverflowError in Java at 19635th the integer in Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: java, stack-overflow, biginteger, fibonacci

I used the following code to calculate the Fibonacci sequence out to an arbitrarily large digit. The code worked as expected until I asked it to call the function 4,000,000 times (previously I only did a few hundred) and the computer ran for a little while, then the console in Eclipse generated the exceptions which I pasted below the code.

My question is what happened here exactly? Did my computer run completely out of memory or memory allocated to the thread? If so, why did it stop at this digit specifically?

Additional: How would I calculate further digits of the Fibonacci Sequence?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class fibonacci2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    calculate(p,q);

}
static long i = 0;
static BigInteger p = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
static BigInteger q = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
static BigInteger temp = BigInteger.valueOf(1);

public static void calculate(BigInteger s,BigInteger t){
    while(i<4000000){       
        System.out.printf("%d\t%d\n", p, i);
        temp = p;
        p = p.add(q);
        q = temp;
        i++;
        calculate(p,q);
        }
    }

}
```

Exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4502)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4500)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4500)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4466)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4177)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4502)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4500)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Start.match(Pattern.java:3408)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.search(Matcher.java:1199)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.find(Matcher.java:618)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2517)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2469)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at fibonacci2.calculate(fibonacci2.java:19)
    at fibonacci2.calculate(fibonacci2.java:24)
```

Last Digit Generated:   19635 - Quite a large number.

132687895548902466181366635978648936386259759626784159198471844113368720762558998439244647213670836266002193258488843538717586491362100768690744948872614655533963444005758146274483789445525832018171591705801097245938131666262491251573046333399064124825294626375827326373349437140811166679924860265434837435457566510346823522099708782762283340421872152967954697149679070291775852559319530410970741909107854532260299713987604089848331720784324541846051983900879941503950602855721502515831654718683894999456728434816859475155877430343774997661435320771926617215280039933599972465309345254567178339436280952174619541825862884767075607549690650640847821947665184588889102910848010077578318155209477877401207558117424629193877673216227666300792666026188581069615968439885076613046674989223796136897853735065950338488718459072802993894034602966485409833232527607580300466868397366391196516624465562328897666935339268449377325653828646145985110998531659421856703633111062016650375200285896034594800936872091294839900191091698699722026536243666478579994343910947620181792632830778710190311139396156735880074125397511408966605505552422864103569572257613749591889214289715689869250327711408697220359084539413697662799047739270265811002163302937592845234417596161934244642557769201791982828989296516960843921418505825929942814213639292708769436360663239620071203876284640114617617407623573142799950934154067036543593696242108211895742765733512094057256880955310857577903859564579056746531798738498941813073521535219704445493818404188856023980301868618516469829419121757591230096104147125384637901683811153945850319934065084792517083004130890910462024025472721271948569599123360701230540009715282093017067167999678658635663087411610488550002425545947760514500156025301308306327998659164369104269073668157017876181974674317395355412084217340614118259465040019942533175911244270084308389583553447943104546514782390571844604018802721936904404474688189087095735594169734604764561595142228281276547574197914091694854554413589159098499442131625356509906287285672050080215052926747681492642423016441535060701812422382650607369780485598683879561606185899006941448935168420562235626599835745827700295226714246314734017810402964725369860652473776199131459371207950362024398152881453713163784066208042563543662925682842776015262230520391615679652089970517416773429690840845145299626705629719042357249513002595223367277901469344821405379464226668034873875307681491568655204909774495913318375555411759980733171712799322946052444470529341466911138600782570876081467456539333314140771233788511026610245435362670217650351862005123494882440312897401664665221934387408681977959790208001158782272459157216112763316198348542078709999150647564964914134863576486661123746003816160948281150545905672098416477331230622651937768742259299137290941586718911557287342694235083529941819644830145463692894576389371194864252193944417249897576680296390036537160332193922853706900504472769773990832173851162215971909022315739548513111748800103501077095982227131161490400275473107114332912752011610992580490036511357042388077219595501595468366432307357375880006328534616109858423036370917076730066512411190813621221988225618801514574381383356699324113692094796970907449469370840049016526662652443809582291319790185342414255291466570332572158841433975328662164311338016851917370479429992007019036364259295950990281576909594760700939581856439476140480808306810823166903862127117572512965716293308583147623766349722954222044113540493984352460455112546555172777189839005308333201885114142111466980905352254535229665410122041438242484536491005787248286883103481601236212094585289510473442558333280384128931643793870559016908029727399281143275162091549243434338130582159038730877484562313951468088162467051046285384314515884048806797355786962180264599960373185136442715557997632215843672184608917328982657966403817121847386761897944779500570824073280196574484365145711215918884480648724038858502746307173620602683682907969598382920518177738917655303213381000153176621747937338966968659109054686337516427263532942648787865802396994723787388617964385931023490

Comment: You're calling `calculate()` from inside `calculate()`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `BigInteger`, this is happening because your `calculate()` method is calling itself.  Once you've gotten your call stack deep enough, you run out of memory and the JVM throws the `StackOverflowError`.

You don't have any sort of termination condition in your `calculate()` method.  Each time you enter the `while` loop, you kick off another call.

In fact, it seems like you are trying to solve this both iteratively and recursively at the same time.

You shouldn't need both a while loop and a recursive call in your code.  It looks to me like if you just take out the call to `calculate()` your program will work just fine:

```
public static void calculate(BigInteger s, BigInteger t) {
    while (i < 4000000) {
        System.out.printf("%d\t%d\n", p, i);
        temp = p;
        p = p.add(q);
        q = temp;
        i++;
        // calculate(p, q); // you don't need this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the error occurs because you're using recursion and never returning from the recursive call.

This is the classic example of why you shouldn't use recursion when iteration will work.  The Fibonacci sequence is mathematically *defined* recursively, but calculating it recursively is very memory intensive because of the number of stack frames you end up using.  You could go farther by increasing the available memory but you will ALWAYS run out at some point.

Given the way you've coded it there's no way to get around this limit other than to rewrite it as an iterative calculation.

Comment: His version oś perfectly valid but only if language supports TCO. Java don't.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is infinitely recursing. You need to remove: `calculate(p, q);` from your code. Since your code is infinitely recursing, a StackOverflowError will be thrown even when you add more memory to Java (which just delays the throwing of that error) since you are using too many stack frames (and thus, too much memory).